# Load content without refreshing page in views

Tags: views, media

i am trying to create a view with pagination. In this view i have images and fivestar rating for it. When user clicks on next i want next image and fivestar to load with out refreshing page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the [views load more module](https://drupal.org/project/views_load_more)

> This module has some very key differences then the other load more
>   module.
>
> - Provide ajax/no-ajax views load more
> - Works with views default ajax implementation, no hacks (check/uncheck ajax)
> - Supports the Waypoints module for loading on various points, Such as when the scroller is visable on the page.
> - Supports the Fade effect when loading new content